# My Google App Engine Wordpress Site is returning response code 500 out of nowhere

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I haven't made any changes at all to my Wordpress install of Google App Engine site and now it won't display any content (except for the home page).

Any time I request a page, it loads the page structure, but not the content and in the logs, it shows a response 500.

I assume this means it can't connect to the database, but I have no idea how to test for this, and because we have the bronze plan, there is no customer service. So even though I haven't made any changes, my site is essentially down, but I have no idea what changed or why.

Can anyone help point me to what I should look for?  Or any resources to help?

Here is the site: http://www.simonsaysgive.org/who-we-are/our-mission-and-vision

Thanks!
Lou

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue on http://www.coworking-radolfzell.de since some time. Upgraded to the latest version 4.1.1 of WordPress locally 2 days ago and deployed it to app engine, after which is was OK, but when I checked back today it was again broken. Very frustrating.

Comment: Ugh ... I spent 40 hours trying to get Wordpress going on GAE ... including the time to convince our organization it was the right thing to do ... and now we have press coming to our site.  This looks really bad for us .. time to dump GAE, I think :(

Comment: It must be connecting to the database because there are some pages with content. and the menu etc. is there.  Have you recently installed any plugins or edited any PHP files?

Comment: It seems that app engine changed something on their end which causes this, because my last code change before upgrading to 4.1.1 was on December 23, 2014 which is when I also upgraded the Google App Engine for WordPress plugin from v1.4 to v1.5. All was fine after that until no content was being displayed any more sometime last week.

Comment: Do you see anything error message your logs?

Comment: I have someone looking at it now and they found a SQL error.  I've not touched the site in weeks.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question title, because response code 200 actually means everything is OK ;-)

Comment: Thanks Nick (edit done).

Comment: From the logs:

`Failed opening required '/base/data/home/apps/s~ssg-wordpress-site/1-2.382075258236135244/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~ssg-wordpress-site/1-2.382075258236135244/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/s~ssg-wordpress-site/1-2.382075258236135244/wordpress/wp-content/themes/simonsaysgive.theme/functions/forms.php on line 16`
line 16 reads:
`require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');`
And I can't seem to find where $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is defined

Comment: Seems we have different issues here. I don't get any 500 errors, only 200. Just realized that Google App Engine for WordPress plugin v1.6 was released 2 days ago, so I just upgraded and now my site works again. Hopefully it will still work tomorrow ;-)

Good luck with sorting your issue. Your error message seems to be quite descriptive.

Comment: The site seems to be up - but I don't see any SQL errors in your logs. What was the error?

Comment: Here's what we did:

1. shut down all running instances (there were 2)
2. flush memcache

Magically, the site was running again ... no telling if this problem will appear again, nor what caused it. 

But I did find out I'm unable to use the GAE Launcher to deploy now (it opens my browser to authenticate, then redirects back to the localhost afterward, only to not be running GAE locally since it's in the middle of a deployment)

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to resolve the issue, though I wouldn't call it a fix.

1. shut down all running instances (there were 2)
2. flush memcache

Then site was magically running again.

I did also tweet to @googlecloud and they've opened a ticket for me.  I'll add it if they find uncover any causes/fixes.

Comment: My problem is back, so the new version of Google App Engine for WordPress plugin did not do the trick for me.

Comment: I just filed a bug report, because I'm pretty sure this must be one http://goo.gl/Xt9ELE.

Comment: Did you try killing all the instances and flushing the memcache?  I'll be sure to include the link to this thread when googlecloud team reaches out.

Comment: I'm not using memcache. Today I changed my runtime from php to php55 in app.yaml and re-deployed the app. That was ~9 hour ago and since then the site has been up and running fine. Hopefully it will still be fine tomorrow ;-)