# Wordpress on Google App Engine randomly crashes with error 500 and white page

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I have a Wordpress 4.1.1 site hosted on GAE, and it crashes almost once a day, i.e. it returns a blank page with an error 500. No other debug informations are provided in the GAE dashboard.

I'm using the GAE plugin 1.6, and I turned on WP debug flag, but this doesn't give anything.

I can reset the site by shutting down GAE instances, which clears the bug. But after several hours, the site crashes again.

I know that this issue has already been reported in [My Google App Engine Wordpress Site is returning response code 500 out of nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753565/my-google-app-engine-wordpress-site-is-returning-response-code-500-out-of-nowher), but it does not give me any solution.

I already tried to enable PHP 5.5, but it doesn't help, the site still crashes.

Here is the list of additional plugin and theme turned on:

- Contact Form 7
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- RSS Image Feed
- WP-PageNavi
- Hueman theme

Answer (score 1):

Please try add the following line to your php.ini
apc.enable = 0

OR

add the following 2 lines to your app: 
 apc_delete('_ah_app_identity_:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only');
 apc_delete('_ah_app_identity_:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write');

as reported at: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11718

Regards,
Paolo

Comment: Thanks Paolo, I made the modification you suggested, and deployed the project. I'll post the result. Thanks again.